# How can i make a frequency dependent switch?

Tags: rf, circuit-design, frequency, radio, circuits

**Is it possible to make a circuit/switch that turns a relay *ON* whenever there is a certain RF frequency applied and keeps it *OFF* for all other frequencies.**

The RF signal should not carry any information, just a sine wave.

i have this FreqModulated signal in the order of a few hundred kHz, its more like an FSK signal comprising only two frequencies, and i have two relays, i want to make a circuit in such a way that when the upper freq is being radiated one relay should turn ON, and when the lower frequency comes the other one should turn ON

If it is possible please give a sample circuit diagram

Comment: Applied through a wire? Or wirelessly?

Comment: applied through a wire

Comment: RF through wire?

Comment: @tlfong01 why not?

Comment: if there is an antenna, there follows an LNA or amplifier, the amplifier's output will come in a wire right? so i just need a circuit/switch that will turn ON for a certain frequency

Comment: @Anche Pavan Kumar, I understand radio waves travel in the air, so it is wireless. Of course you can use a radio receiver to receive the signal and convert it to wired serial..

Comment: Sounds like you want a band-pass filter followed by an integrator.  We need a lot more details about what you are trying to do to get more detailed than that.

Comment: I once played with 2.4GHz transceiver nRF24L01, you might like to see what I mean by RF: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/how-can-rpi-communicate-with-arduino-in-rf-radio-frequency.

Comment: i have this FreqModulated signal in the order of a few hundred kHz, its more like an FSK signal comprising only two frequencies, and i have two relays, i want to make a circuit in such a way that when the upper freq is being radiated one relay should turn ON, and when the lower frequency comes the other one should turn ON

Comment: So my suggestion is that your friend at the far side transmits you rubbish at 2.4GHz, you at your side detects rubbish and switch on the relay.

Comment: @tlfong01 your comments seem to be largely unrelated to what is discussed or asked here. And you're generally wrong, radio waves don't only travel in the air.

Comment: What there is no carrier or they alternate quickly?   A simple solution is a comparator with a stable 4046 PLL to detect the frequency as a voltage or a  precision Tach circuit that does the same to convert f to V then a comparator for 0 or 1 . What is the deviation in f? 50% 5% ?

Comment: @Marcus Müller, Thank you very much pointing out my silly mistake. So I now know that radio wave doesn't travel (only) in the air (or Ether), because it can actually travel in (vacuum) space where there is no air. Though long long time ago once learnt in my middle school physics lessons that long waves can be reflected by some sort of atmosphere ionised layers, and that is why our radio receivers can receive broadcasts thousands of miles away. My apology for my ignorance. I just want to share my hobbyist experience of 2.4GHz toys. Anyway, I will shut up for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, sounds like a bandpass filter, followed by a power detector. Detection can be as  easy as a diode rectifier followed by a simple RC lowpass. Feed that into a transistor as switch. Amplification might be necessary at some step.

Sorry that it's not more specific than that, but you probably know that in  RF engineering, things *very* much depend on the actual frequency range you work at, and since you've not given that, you are probably just looking for a general approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider using one of these: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This was done with the trick LED series cct. Each series switch sends some HF current and each series LED receives some parallel LC HF voltage to drive LED , so a single wire loop can select the matching LED and the C conducts the other freq. current and while the L blocks the voltage.  So the switch connects the L//C while conducts then each LED has L//C  both tuned to each other while frequency separation must be wide enough to prevent each filter de-tuning each other too much

Comment: Ah, I never heard of LED series circuit. As usual I find your tutorial too hard for newbies. Let me use my newebie language. Say there is one LED series switch transmitter, consists of a battery, a manual switch, in series with a L/C thing. Now when you flip the switch (off only?) there is a HF signal travelling through air to the other side where there is a similar LED series cct with the same L/C (filter/resonator), (but no switch is required) which "resonates" with the signal of the same frequency. The LED lights, and LED voltage can be amplified to turn on a relay. So it is sort of FSK.

Comment: No. The switch is N.O. And the caps all conduct enough for any one LED to rectify current. Each Parallel inductor in the LED resonates the produce voltage at the selected frequency.

Comment: Oh my goodness, so I was too clever to guess that the LED is a status lamp to notify the human that a message is coming by. Ah, you remind me one thing, so the diode acts as a rectifier, converting the oscillator AC signal to DC. And the signal become SSB (Single Side Band) then you can do amplitude modulation. I must confess that even I did pass my EE diploma course (and also London City and Guild wireless operator (sort of HAM) cert), but my interest is playing with the walki talki toy, not that much in boring theory. Anyway, I need google to relearn things I know but never understand.

Comment: Rectifiers DONT make SSB

Comment: OMG, you remind me the English idiom: "***You got it all wrong!***".  But, just now when I tried to recall the City and Guild stuff, I suddenly remember another associated thing (yes, my associated memory power has not yet demented), my C&G exam cert actually lists two parts of results: (1) Practical and (2) Theory, I remember very vividly the joy when I saw the words "Theory - "***Pass with Credit***". My associated memory also reminded this: I once took GCE A Level exams, me ***AL Physics Passed with Distinction***. Oh well, those were the days : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3KEhWTnWvE.

Comment: Ah, not at all. It is US deleting HK, and UK deleting EU.

Comment: Talking about US, my associated memory reminded me of my American Dream (and my SAT results!). But that is a little bit off topic, so let us go back to Single Side Band Modulation. Firstly, I confess that the EE75 guy is correct in pointing out that the HKTCEExx guy is all wrong, at least on SSB. To verify his verdict, I wikied:(1)"Single-sideband modulation":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sideband_modulation. Then I have a pleasant surprise, / to continue, ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the required schematic.

[image]

Comment: If this picture is not yours please provide a source

Comment: This schematic is mine!